# How to configure FactoryBot files path in a Rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

For my first Ruby on Rails engine - named **"glossary"** - I wish to implement Rspec, ShouldaMatchers, FactoryBot as test suite. Things look good, but FactoryBot keeps claiming that factories are not registered:

```
Failures:

  1) Glossary::User   
     Failure/Error: subject {FactoryBot.build(:user)}

     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: user
```

In the development process,
`rails generate model user first_name last_name user_name` created the following files:

- app/models/glossary/user.rb
- db/migrate/20180731061831_create_glossary_users.rb
- spec/models/glossary/user_spec.rb
- spec/factories/glossary_users.rb

which looks good.

**rails_helper.rb** contains the following:

```
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
    require File.expand_path('../dummy/config/environment.rb', __FILE__)

    require 'spec_helper'

    # Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
    abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
    require 'rspec/rails'
    require 'shoulda/matchers'
    require 'factory_bot_rails'
    FactoryBot.definition_file_paths << File.expand_path('../spec/factories', __FILE__)

---

    # Fred 2018-07-29: added to engine configuration
    Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
      config.integrate do |with|
        # Choose a test framework:
        with.test_framework :rspec

        # Choose one or more libraries:
        with.library :rails
      end
    end

    # spec/support/factory_bot.rb
    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
    end
```

**lib/glossary/engine.rb** contains the following:

```
module Glossary
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Glossary

    # Fred 2018-07-29: added to engine configuration
    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot 
      g.factory_bot dir: 'spec/factories' 
    end
  end
end
```

FactoryBot generated this **spec/factories/glossary_users.rb** file:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :glossary_user, class: 'Glossary::User' do
    first_name "MyString"
    last_name "MyString"
    user_name "MyString"
  end
end
```

which I refer to in the **spec/models/glossary/user_spec.rb** file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

module Glossary
  RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
    describe 'Validations'
    subject {FactoryBot.build(:user)}
      it { should validate_presence_of(:user_name) }

  end
end
```

Nevertheless, issuing the following command in the rails console does not                                                               return the expected path, and factories remain not found:

```
Fred:glossary$ rails console                                                                                                                 
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.0)                                                                                                                   
irb(main):001:0> FactoryBot.find_definitions                                                                                                                    
=> ["/var/www/glossary/spec/dummy/factories", "/var/www/glossary/spec/dummy/test/factories", "/var/www/glossary/spec/dummy/spec/factories"]                     
irb(main):002:0>
```

Did I miss something in the setup or configuration?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm looking through the config for an engine I wrote that is using FactoryBot and the only difference I see in the config are these 2: `FactoryBot.definition_file_paths << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'factories')` & I also call find_definitions in the config file `FactoryBot.find_definitions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Factory have name `glossary_user` and should used as `FactoryBot.build(:glossary_user)`

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar problem, I rearranged my code as

```rb
# rails_helper.rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# for factory bot
require 'factory_bot_rails'
```

And my test.rb as

```rb
# test.rb
config.eager_load = false
# some config
config.factory_bot.definition_file_paths += ["<my path"]
```

Edit 1: Explanation
So FactoryBot scans the directories present in `FactoryBot.definition_file_paths` and registers all the factories by invoking `FactoryBot.find_definitions`

The `FactoryBot.find_definitions` invocation occurs when we

```rb
require 'factory_bot_rails`
```

Hence the order of statements inside `rails_helper.rb` matters

Edit 2: The above solution disregards the typo in factory usage as pointed out by others

Answer (score 0):

This will make factories that you define in your engine available to the apps that depend on your engine.

In your `lib/my_engine/engine.rb`:

```rb
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

    initializer :load_factories, after: 'factory_bot.set_factory_paths' do
      if defined?(FactoryBot) && defined?(Faker) && !Rails.env.production?
        FactoryBot.definition_file_paths.prepend(
          File.join(MyEngine.root, 'spec', 'factories')
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I like to protect it with a conditional to ensure it only runs under the appropriate conditions. You can find other variations on this in the [FactoryBot codebase](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails/blob/v6.4.3/features/load_definitions.feature#L121).